# OpenGL Add Vertices After Load

Tags: ios, c, opengl-es

I am parsing a 3D file into OpenGL ES on an iOS device and after I get the vertices I can't seem to add them to the GLfloat containing my vertices. At the top of my file I declare this GLFloat:

```
    GLfloat gFileVertices[] = {
        -0.686713, 0.346845, 3.725390,          -0.000288, -0.000652, -0.000109,
        -0.677196, 0.350971, 3.675733,          -0.000288, -0.000652, -0.000109, 
        -0.673889, 0.340921, 3.726985,          -0.000288, -0.000652, -0.000109, 
        -0.677424, 0.337048, 3.775731,          -0.000283, -0.000631, -0.000071, 
        And so on...
    }
```

But how can I put that same data (x,y,z normal.x, normal.y, normal.z) into that array in an instance in which each of those are variables and there are a variable number of rows?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to calculate that data that I have given an example of above but for a unique file that the user of my app choses. So what I don't understand how to do is take that data after I calculated it for that file and then put it into the gFileVertices variable. The problem is that I have to account for a variable amount of rows and if I put a for loop to print out each line of calculated vertices and normals in gFileVertices then I get an error because I can't put code in gFileVertices only numbers.

Comment: You should reconsider your question tags, this is more related to `C` programming than `opengl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to allocate the vertices buffer dynamically at runtime, rather than statically at compile time. In your code there is no way to change the size of gFileVertices once the program is compiled.

For management purposes I will instead use separate normals and vertices array instead of interleaving the data into one.

To parse the file, determine the number of vertices and allocate buffers.

```
GLfloat* verticesBuff = malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * vertCount * 3); /* 3 floats per vert */
GLfloat* normalsBuff = malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * vertCount * 3); /* 3 floats per vert */
```

Then copy each element into the new array:

```
  /* read from file or whatevs */
  for (int i = 0; i < vertCount; i ++)
  {
      verticesBuff[i * 3] = ... 
      verticesBuff[i * 3 + 1] = ...
      verticesBuff[i * 3 + 2] = ... 

      normalsBuff[i * 3] = ... 
      normalsBuff[i * 3 + 1] = ... 
      normalsBuff[i * 3 + 2] = ... 

  }
```

The dynamic arrays can be used in OpenGL just like the static:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuff); 
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normalsBuff);
```

Thats it! Just make sure to delete when you are done:

```
free(verticesBuff);
free(normalsBuff);
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I set the three separate floats for each vertices and normal?

Comment: @user1795671 sorry I made a mistake - edited to show how each element is assigned.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand, I would put the first code snippet in my viewDidLoad or when I setup openGL, I put that second code snipped in with my own calculated data after I parse my 3D file, and the 3rd part in my openGL setup and call the setup again once entering the second part, and the last snippet is to be used to unload those buffers on dealloc?

Comment: @user1795671 correct - exactly what needs to happen! Except the 3rd part is actually right before drawing with glDrawArrays.

Comment: Awesome. I just tried that, and I am getting these really weird and inconsistent crashes that all lead to that code, more specifically it's always crashing at a line of code that I am setting the normals in, but not a consistent axis of normals... Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: @user1795671 make sure vertCount is correct and glDrawArrays number is correct.

Comment: I think I am. I have narrowed the problem to setting the normals buffer. If I take out the code setting that then it's fine, otherwise it crashes every time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33371/discussion-between-user1795671-and-justin-meiners)